# How can I show this inequality between series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Prove that $\forall \{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ $\exists k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{n}{A_1+\cdots+A_n}}\leq k \cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{A_n}}$

I already know that the case when $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$ converges we gey the inequality $\infty\leq\infty$ but I don't know what to do when $\sum{A_n}$ diverges.

**Edit**: we are assuming that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{j}{A_i}\neq 0 \quad \forall j\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Presumably $A_i$ is also non-negative?

Comment: i think, but the enunciate doesn't say anything

Comment: Do we assume the series on the LHS is converging?

Comment: Its converges for $\sum{A_n}$ diverging sufficiently fast (>n^2) but I'm not sure what happens in the other case

Comment: I think this problem has been discussed [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975257/if-sum-n-1-infty-frac1a-n-converges-must-sum-n-1-infty-fracn)